# "Invalid value of "%value" provided for the %fieldName field" Error in reset forgot password from multiwebsite

Tags: customer-account, magento2.2.3

We have multi website (country wise) in Magento2 and the customers are shared through the multi website. In each website only the default country is allowed through Magento backend.

While resetting password from other website/country other than the default address, country getting error "Invalid value of "IN" provided for the country field". While it is working fine if the default address, and the allowed country is same.

So what is the best way to skip this step from AbstractAddress.php file and we cannot allow more than one country for a single website.